# Clang returns different compiler errors for system include files

Tags: c++11, clang

main.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"
void main () {narrowingConversion ();}
```

include/test.h:

```
void narrowingConversion () {int i = 1; char a[1] = {i};}
```

Clang compiles the above code successfuly when including the `include` folder as a system folder:

```
clang++ -std=c++0x -isystem./include main.cpp
```

But clang fails when the folder is included normally:

```
clang++ -std=c++0x -I./include main.cpp
```

> ./include/test.h:1:54: error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'char' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]

**Question:** Why does clang behaves differently for system and non system files?

Comment: @jens Are you sure this is not related to `c`? This problem may occur for c warnings/errors too.

Comment: @m7913d People are extremely reflexive about removing C or C++ tags on questions where they don't immediately see the relevance to both. I get that this is based on legitimate instances of mis-tagging, but I think folk overcorrect too much. However, in this case, I can see their point: while I'm quite certain this will be the same for C, without an example of Clang exhibiting the same behaviour, the question as written is just about C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clang suppresses warnings for system headers by default. It seems to deem C++11 narrowing a non-fatal error and to suppress diagnostics about that in this context.

As per [the manual](http://releases.llvm.org/3.7.0/tools/clang/docs/UsersManual.html), to see this when the header was `#include`d from a directory deemed to be a system one (which `-Isystem` specifies), you'd need to enable this option:

> `-Wsystem-headers`
>
> Enable warnings from system headers.

This flag is probably inherited from GCC, to which it [was added in 2000](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2000-05/msg01044.html). The [rationale](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html) for that was:

> The header files declaring interfaces to the operating system and runtime libraries often cannot be written in strictly conforming C. Therefore, GCC gives code found in system headers special treatment. All warnings, other than those generated by ‘`#warning`’ (see [Diagnostics](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Diagnostics.html#Diagnostics)), are suppressed while GCC is processing a system header. Macros defined in a system header are immune to a few warnings wherever they are expanded. […]

[m7913d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7621674/m7913d) [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44824874/clang-returns-different-compiler-errors-for-system-include-files/44825079?noredirect=1#comment76631130_44825079) the equivalent section of the Clang documentation, which doesn't give as much exposition as GCC did:

> More information can be found here: [Controlling Diagnostics in System Headers](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-in-system-headers)

But the core result is the same:

> Warnings are suppressed when they occur in system headers.

And, as we've seen, Clang seems to consider C++11 narrowing not to be a hard error, and to suppress it for system headers in the absence of `-Wsystem-headers`.

Comment: Not a bad hypothesis, but it looks like it is an _error_, not only a warning

Comment: I presume, until demonstrated otherwise, that at least some errors are also included under that banner. For instance, C++11 narrowing errors only requires a vaguely defined "diagnostic", not failure to compile. Maybe that factors into this. Of course, you can test this by adding `-Wsystem-headers` to the original case and seeing what it says then.

Comment: Adding `-Wsystem-headers` indeed result in the narrowing error, even for system files.

Comment: More information can be found here: [Controlling Diagnostics in System Headers](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-in-system-headers)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and the extra link! I'll add that to my answer too.